# Linux: How to pass a file content as an argument to a command?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

this is the content of the **packageList** file:

```
base-files
busybox
dnsmasq
dropbear
firewall
hotplug2
iptables
iptables-mod-conntrack-extra
iptables-mod-filter
iptables-mod-ipopt
iw
jshn
kernel
kmod-ath
kmod-ath9k
kmod-ath9k-common
kmod-cfg80211
kmod-crypto-aes
kmod-crypto-arc4
kmod-crypto-core
kmod-gpio-button-hotplug
kmod-ifb
kmod-ipt-conntrack
kmod-ipt-conntrack-extra
kmod-ipt-core
kmod-ipt-filter
kmod-ipt-ipopt
kmod-ipt-nat
kmod-ipt-nathelper
kmod-leds-gpio
kmod-ledtrig-default-on
kmod-ledtrig-netdev
kmod-ledtrig-timer
kmod-lib-crc-ccitt
kmod-lib-textsearch
kmod-mac80211
kmod-nls-base
kmod-ppp
kmod-pppoe
kmod-pppox
kmod-sched-connmark
kmod-sched-core
kmod-tun
kmod-wdt-ath79
libblobmsg-json
libc
libgcc
libip4tc
libip6tc
libiwinfo
libiwinfo-lua
libjson
liblua
liblzo
libnfnetlink
libnl-tiny
libopenssl
libubox
libubus
libubus-lua
libuci
libuci-lua
libxtables
lua
luci
luci-app-firewall
luci-app-qos
luci-app-tinyproxy
luci-app-upnp
luci-i18n-english
luci-lib-core
luci-lib-ipkg
luci-lib-nixio
luci-lib-sys
luci-lib-web
luci-mod-admin-core
luci-mod-admin-full
luci-proto-core
luci-proto-ppp
luci-proto-relay
luci-sgi-cgi
luci-theme-base
luci-theme-openwrt
miniupnpd
mtd
netifd
openvpn
opkg
ppp
ppp-mod-pppoe
qos-scripts
relayd
swconfig
tc
tinyproxy
uboot-envtools
ubus
ubusd
uci
uhttpd
wpad-mini
zlib
```

now I would like to pass it as argument to:

make image PROFILE=TLWR740 PACKAGES=**packageList**

this is BASH, how go do it? the content should be passed as argument in this way:

base-files busybox dnsmasq dropbear firewall hotplug2 iptables iptables-mod-conntrack-extra iptables-mod-filter iptables-mod-ipopt iw jshn kernel kmod-ath kmod-ath9k kmod-ath9k-common kmod-cfg80211 kmod-crypto-aes kmod-crypto-arc4 kmod-crypto-core kmod-gpio-button-hotplug kmod-ifb kmod-ipt-conntrack kmod-ipt-conntrack-extra kmod-ipt-core kmod-ipt-filter kmod-ipt-ipopt kmod-ipt-nat kmod-ipt-nathelper kmod-leds-gpio kmod-ledtrig-default-on kmod-ledtrig-netdev kmod-ledtrig-timer kmod-lib-crc-ccitt kmod-lib-textsearch kmod-mac80211 kmod-nls-base kmod-ppp kmod-pppoe kmod-pppox kmod-sched-connmark kmod-sched-core kmod-tun kmod-wdt-ath79 libblobmsg-json libc libgcc libip4tc libip6tc libiwinfo libiwinfo-lua libjson liblua liblzo libnfnetlink libnl-tiny libopenssl libubox libubus libubus-lua libuci libuci-lua libxtables lua luci luci-app-firewall luci-app-qos luci-app-tinyproxy luci-app-upnp luci-i18n-english luci-lib-core luci-lib-ipkg luci-lib-nixio luci-lib-sys luci-lib-web luci-mod-admin-core luci-mod-admin-full luci-proto-core luci-proto-ppp luci-proto-relay luci-sgi-cgi luci-theme-base luci-theme-openwrt miniupnpd mtd netifd openvpn opkg ppp ppp-mod-pppoe qos-scripts relayd swconfig tc tinyproxy uboot-envtools ubus ubusd uci uhttpd wpad-mini zlib

Comment: Try make image PROFILE=TLWR740 PACKAGES=$(cat packageList)

Comment: Or you can use that, too.

Comment: doesn't work unfortunatelly. I believe it's because it is passing the list as one name per line, not side-by-side.

Comment: use quotes: `PACKAGES="$(cat packageList)"` so that the entire list is passed as a single parameter.

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Comment: Whether it's side by side or in a new line should not matter for parsing arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it that way:

1. Declare variable `$packages` as array
2. Read content of file `packageList` into `$packages`
3. Run make with all array elements as list (`${packages[*]}`)

Hence, this snippet should work:

```
declare -a packages
packages=($(< packageList))
make image PROFILE=TLWR740 PACKAGES="${packages[*]}"
```

A comment is appropriate about `${packageList[*]}`. This expands to all array elements as *one shell word*. This is similar if you write `"one two three"` (note the quotes) on the command line.

A simple example, using a function `first`, which prints its *first argument*:

```
$ function first { echo $1 ; }
$ first one two three
one
$ first "one two three"
one two three
```

Now, with an array:

```
$ foo=(one two three)
$ first "${foo[@]}"
one
$ first "${foo[*]}"
one two three
```

So, with `@` the shell splits the array into multiple shell words, using `*` it does not.

Comment: that also didn't work! how can that be possible? it produces no error, but it loads the default list. Probably ignoring the packageList.

Comment: @FernandoSBS Are you sure, the make invocation is correct? Does it work, if you pass two or three packages manually, e.g. `make ... PACKAGES="base-files busybox dnsmasq"`?

Comment: exactly, with manual pass it works.

Comment: Please try `..."${packageList[*]}"` instead. This will pass all packages as one shell word; `${packageList[@]}` splits it into different shell words. (However this should be identical to Shiki's answer, then)

Comment: Still don't work. More info: if I do: `packageList="..."` pasting manually the list of packages in the "..." it works. And when I `cat $packageList` it seems to be returning just `cat: base-files: No such file or directory
` but when I `cat packageList` it returns all the list correctly

Comment: Still don't work. More info: if I do: `packageList="..."` pasting manually the list of packages in the "...", in the format available in the OP (words side by side) it works.

Comment: actually IT DID WORK. Using * solves it. But I'm still confused with the above info I've posted!

Comment: @FernandoSBS I improved my answer accordingly. `cat $packageList` doesn't make sense, as `$packageList` already holds the content of the `packageList` file. Use `echo $packageList` instead. I also changed the name to make the difference between file and variable clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr` to convert the newline characters to spaces:

```
make image PROFILE=TLWR740 "PACKAGES=$( tr '\n' ' ' < packageList)"
```

Seems `tr` only reads stdin so I've modified my command above to pass the file via stdin.

Comment: Also doesn't work. tr: extra operand `packageList'
Try `tr --help' for more information.

Comment: The command expansion should read: `$(cat packageList | tr '\n' ' ')`. IMHO `tr` work's on stdin/out only.

Comment: @FernandoSBS: Did you try `tr --help` ? What did it say? I've edited my answer.

Comment: @mpy: [UUoC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: what do you mean? what for tr --help ?

Answer (score 1):

```
make image PROFILE=TLWR740 PACKAGES="`cat packageList | tr '\n' ' '`"
```

That should do it. `cat` prints the file contents, and the `tr` command replaces the newlines with spaces. (Note: this assumes that `packageList` is a file in the current directory, if it is elsewhere you will need to replace the name to include the correct path or use a variable to reference it)

Comment: This will split the package list over multiple command line arguments. You need to surround it with quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `xargs` command.

To pass the file names from a file to a `cp` command we can do:

```
cat 'file_name'| args -I % cp % destination_directory
```

But if you want to see the how it would echo then:

```
cat 'file_name' | args -I % echo cp % destination_directory
```

This will just echo.

Answer (score 0):

```
List=`cat packageList`  
make image PROFILE=TLWR740 PACKAGES="$List"
```

cat writes out the content of the file. (try it in cli.)

Comment: also doesn't work. I believe it's because it is passing the list as one name per line, not side-by-side.